# Is 0700 or 0711 permission enough to protect database configuration files?

Tags: apache, security, file-permissions, shared-hosting

As we  all know that with shared web hosting other users (websites) files could be revealed to others if 'others' have the (read) permission .

I think 0700 or 0711 permission is the best way( in shared hosting) to protect important files the contain secret information .

I suppose that the server is using suPHP or any similar module so that keep the UID of the process is the same as the owner of the files being accessed.

So what do you say ?

Comment: please add details of what exactly you expect that file to be capable of

Comment: I suppose that this contains information required to connect to the database
Ex:
mysql_connect(host,username,password);

Comment: I have edited my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. 700 would ensure nobody can `read/write/execute` that file, except the owner. So that would be good enough! In case it is to be executed, 711, else, 700.

However, if some operation involving that file fails, you should consider 711.

EDIT: 
As you have mentioned, if it contains a connection string, you can safely assume that nobody needs to be given write privileges, and give everyone execute privileges.
So, 511(which is `r_x __x __x`) should do it.

Comment: Good ..
but i think read privileges is enough cause it NOT a (CGI or perl ) file ..

Comment: Okay, so you will be going for a 500?

Comment: Good luck! If resolved, please update the status of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need **execution** rights **only for directories**, if your files are PHP source files you certainly do not need execution rights.

**0640** and **2750** are usualy good rights for respectively Files and Directories (the 2 in the directory rights make the new files inherit user & group of the directory).

That is for files:

```
-rw-r-----
```

And directories

```
drwxr-s---
```

Which is right if the **webserver is using the group** rights and the FTP-or-such user being the owner. With Suexec and such you could maybe adjust these settings depending of who is the owner and who is the web reader (user? group?), the web reader does not need write access, except maybe on some specific directories depending on the application.

And do not forget files & directories rights are only one point in separation of user in a shared envirronment. For PHP envirronments using per-user **open_basedir** settings, **temporary files** and **upload** directories and per-user **session** directories is always a good idea (that can be defined in per-user virtualhosts).